# How to create a solution folder for a solution in visual studio dynamically?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2017, solution

I want to create a new *Solution Folder* dynamically in Visual Studio using PowerShell script.

I know how to create a solution folder for an existing solution in Visual Studio manually but is there a way we can automate it using PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a *Solution Folder*, you should add a `Project` entry. The Guid for the *Project Type* for a solution folder should be : `"{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}"` and for the project Guid, you should use a new Guid.

Here is a function which adds a folder to a solution file:

```
Function AddFolderToSolution($folderName, $solutionFile)
{
   $solutionFolderGuid = "{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}"
   $content = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($solutionFile)
   $lines = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
   $lines.AddRange($content)
   $index = $lines.IndexOf("Global")
   $guid = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper()
   $txt = "Project(`"$solutionFolderGuid`") = `"$folderName`", `"$folderName`", `"$guid`""
   $lines.Insert($index, $txt)
   $lines.Insert($index+1, "EndProject")
   [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($solutionFile, $lines)
}
```

And here is the usage:

```
AddFolderToSolution "NewFolder10" "D:\Solution1.sln"
```

Comment: Where do I get the Guid?

Comment: The function contains all the logic. Just call it the same way that I called. The Guid for solution folder project type is `"{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}"`. The guid for the folder itself is a new Guid `[System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper()`. The answer contains all required information you don't need to discover anything. I tried it with VS2017 and it worked properly.

Comment: I am getting this error: `Exception calling "Insert" with "2" argument(s): "Index must be within the bounds 
of the List.
Parameter name: index"
At line:12 char:4
+    $lines.Insert($index, $txt)
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
 `

Comment: I'm running it against a VS2017 solution without any problem. Do some debug and make sure the solution file which you have is valid and for exampel contains "Global" entry.

Comment: It worked. My solution had some issues, I fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: I still have one doubt. Will it create a new folder "NewFolder10"? Or I have to create it first and then add that folder to my solution?

Comment: @ANIL The solution folder is not a real physical folder. You don't need to create a folder. The solution folder is a logical folder meaningful just for categorizing some files, which may be located any where.

Comment: If I want to copy few files into that solution folder then how can I do it?

Comment: You should add those items as solution items with relative path to the solution. If those files are in the same directory of the solution, then it would be easier.

Comment: Let me know if you asked a new question regarding to your comment.

Comment: Yes here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637228/how-can-i-add-files-to-a-solution-folder